# Em PT-pt "droga" é entendida como remédio?

Tags: português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

Recentemente li uma [reportagem](http://g1.globo.com/pop-arte/noticia/2016/09/jim-carrey-e-acusado-de-ter-comprado-drogas-que-mataram-ex.html) em que um ator é acusado de "comprar *drogas* que mataram sua ex-namorada". Ao ler a reportagem descobre-se que ele adquiriu remédios, medicamentos, que causaram uma *overdose* letal.

Um dos comentários mais populares na matéria diz:

> Chamada sensacionalista, drogas se referem a remedios, aqui no Brasil o conceito de drogas é outro.

Ao que outro leitor responde:

> O termo "drogas" sempre esteve ligado a remédios, tanto é que existem drogarias, ou seja, lugar onde se vende remédios, drogas, para curar alguma enfermidade.

Sou obrigado a concordar com os 2 leitores, existem *drogarias* no Brasil, mas acho o termo estranho, um tanto quanto antiquado, apesar de ainda ser usado. No entanto, ao ouvir *drogas*, especialmente em uma manchete, imediatamente associo este termo a drogas ilícitas.

**TL;DR;**

Minha dúvida é, como o termo *drogas* (ou mais especificamente, seu uso na manchete mencionada acima) seria entendido em Portugal?

Comment: O argumento da drogaria, a menos que as drogarias no Brasil sejam diferentes das de Portugal, parece-me fraco. Nas drogarias portuguesas vende-se quase tudo exceto medicamentos. Não sei se no passado já se venderam remédios nas drogarias. Diria que o título for tradução apressada do inglês, não?

Comment: @Jacinto nas drogarias vendem-se «drogas» para as plantas e animais, como venenos para ratos, caracóis, etc. E ainda adubos, e repelentes de insetos e organismos, como piolhos das couves.

Comment: @JorgeB. É verdade, e vem daí com certeza (e dos produtos de limpeza, tintas e coisas assim)  o nome *drogaria*. Mas medicamentos, não.

Comment: @Jacinto  O principal produto de venda das drogarias são os medicamentos.  As grandes drogarias do Rio de Janeiro e de São Paulo colocam a venda outros produtos que não são exclusivos de drogarias: xampus, desodorantes, creme dental, preservativos, aparelhos de barbear, etc.  Mas esses produtos também são vendidos em super-mercados.  Medicamentos, no entanto, só em drogarias e farmácias, que por estas bandas podem ser idênticas, embora as farmácias sejam geralmente menores e tendam a não extrapolar muito no que vendem.  Já as drogarias, nos dias de hoje, vendem até chocolates, biscoitos, etc.

Comment: @Centaurus Então as vossas drogarias são mesmo diferentes das nossas: em Portugal, nem medicamentos nem nada alimentar; higiene pessoal talvez. Por exemplo, o que eu compro nas drogarias é petróleo para limpar a bicicleta e, de vez em quanto, desentupidor de canos.

Comment: @Centaurus, para reforçar o que escreveu o Jacinto, espreita de relance [este artigo](https://www.timeout.pt/lisboa/pt/compras/lojas-tradicionais-drogarias), que fala das drogarias como «associadas a armários repletos de objectos que dão um jeitaço lá em casa, como produtos para limpar móveis, frascos e boiões de cosméticos capilares e branqueadores para a roupa». Rola pelo artigo abaixo, e [dificilmente vais achar](https://media.timeout.com/images/104094929/750/562/image.jpg) que sejam espaços em que se vendam medicamentos. :)

Comment: @ANeves  Muito interessante. As grandes redes de drogarias em solo norte americano são então híbridas de nossas (brasileiras e portuguesas) drogarias. Na CVS, Walgreens e outras, encontra-se de tudo (chocolates, xampus, ssabonetes, óculos, biscoitos, detergentes, papel higiênico, etc) além de algumas prteleiras para aqueles medicamentos que são vendidos sem prescrição médica (OTC) e mais um outro balcão reservado onde são vendidas "prescription drugs". As drogarias brasileiras vendem principalmente medicamentos. O nome "farmácia" é cada vez menos visto por aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo o dicionário da priberam,

> **dro·ga** |ó| (francês drogue) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Nome genérico de todos os ingredientes que têm aplicação em várias indústrias bem como na farmácia.
>
> "droga", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/droga [consultado em
>   04-10-2016].

Tendo em conta o contexto da pergunta eu diria que o título é sensacionalista mesmo, eu ao ler isso acharia que seriam drogas como cocaína ou heroína. Depois de ler o sub-titulo dá a ideia que é MD ou ecstasy.

Por outro lado não é de todo descabido que se use «droga» como medicamento, mas dependeria do contexto, por exemplo:

> - Eu tomo 26 comprimidos por dia para as doenças que tenho.
> - Tu tomas muitas drogas!

Mas diria que, na generalidade, a palavra «droga» é usada para casos em que nos referimos a MD, ecstasy, cocaína, heroína, etc.

Comment: Eu diria que o título, dado que no Brasil *droga* é usado como cá, foi uma tradução apressada do inglês.

Comment: @Jacinto também poderá ser. Mas também não me admirava que fosse sensacionalista.

Comment: Também poderá muito bem ser.

Comment: Acredito que a referência à droga seja por ser remédio de uso controlado, alguns possuem efeitos semelhantes a drogas ilícitas ou são fabricados com 'derivados' como lidocaína, codeína, morfina...

Comment: @Jacinto  e Jorge B,  noto que os falantes de pt-PT evitam o uso do futuro do pretérito bem mais do que os falantes de pt-BR.  Notem:  "não me admirava que fosse sensacionalista", "Também poderá ser".  Também ouvi esses tempos verbais com alguma frequência durante minhas andanças pelas Terras de José Régio. Eu usaria "admiraria" e "poderia" embora eu encontre por aqui algumas pessoas que preferem o imperfeito.

Comment: @Centaurus O uso do imperfeito no lugar do condicional/futuro do pretérito é padrão em Portugal, exceto em linguagem formal. Creio que há até um pergunta aqui sobre isso. O meu «poderá» é diferente. Eu ali poderia ter usado o presente: o autor escreveu aquilo no passado, mas o escrito existe ainda hoje. Usei o futuro no lugar do presente para exprimir incerteza, embora o «pode» já o fizesse também. E acho que também já há um pergunta sobre isto :)

Answer (score 7):

Em pt-BR a palavra "droga", como sinônimo de medicamento, não é de uso popular mas é muito comum no meio científico. A indústria farmacêutica, os médicos, pesquisadores, biólogos, etc, usam-na frequentemente.  e.g. "Uma nova droga foi descoberta para o tratamento do Mal de Alzheimer", "Tal droga não faz parte do meu armamentarium terapêutico devido a seus efeitos colaterais".

A própria definição de "droga" inclui perfeitamente aquilo que popularmente chamamos de remédio ou medicamento: [**"Droga é toda e qualquer substância, natural ou sintética que, introduzida no organismo modifica suas funções."**](http://www.antidrogas.com.br/oquedrogas.php)  Contudo, nem toda droga é um medicamento (cianeto, arsênico e álcool metílico não o são) e nem todo remédio é uma droga (agentes físicos como calor, frio, ultrassom e radioatividade são exemplos)  E como foi bem citado pelo OP, "drogarias" são locais onde podemos adquirir as drogas lícitas. Contudo, admito que a palavra "droga" fora de contexto, ou dependendo do contexto, suscita de imediato no brasileiro leigo a idéia de uma substância proibida, uma "droga ilícita" do tipo cocaína, maconha, heroína, etc.  Um bom exemplo é a manchete citada na pergunta.

Não é a resposta a como "droga" é entendida em pt-PT, mas achei importante acrescentar algum conhecimento a cerca de como a mesma palavra é entendida no Brasil.

Comment: É exatamente o mesmo em Portugal. Também se usa muito no meio cientifico e em medicina, mas numa manchete como essa a interpretação mais saliente seria a de que a droga era ilícita.

Comment: Centaurus, na tua douta opinião uma espada pode tecnicamente contar como uma «substância sintética que, introduzida no organismo, modifica as suas funções»? haha :)

Comment: @ANeves  (risos) Bem, aqui vai a resposta.  A princípio pode parecer que uma espada se enquadra na definição de droga.  No entanto, não é uma substancia e nem o material do qual ela é feita não interage com o organismo.  O efeito é puramente mecânico, traumático.